# Prevent right scrolling of uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which can be scrolled horizontally. However, I want right scrolling to be disabled until a specific condition has been met. What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `scrollViewDidScroll` in your `UIScrollView` delegate.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollview {
  CGPoint contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset;
  if (!yourCondition && contentOffset.x > 0) {
    contentOffset.x = 0;
    scrollview.contentOffset = contentOffset;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add an observer `forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` and handle the `UIScrollView` bounds changes there instead.

You could also add:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollview withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
  if (!yourCondition && targetContentOffset->x > 0) {
    targetContentOffset->x = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, however I sometimes get a slight 'bounce' in the opposite direction when hitting the offset limit. This happens especially when I swipe wast across the screen. I think it has something to do with the deceleration value.

Comment: You could stop the deceleration the way that I've edited my answer.